# Games don't fit in screen when launched in full screen mode (show only left-top quarter)

Tags: technical-issues, windows, monitor, windows-8

I'm trying to play games on a Windows 8.1 tablet with 1900x1200 resolution.

When I run some games which change resolution I see only their left-top quarter like game thinks that it's still 1900x1200 when it actually uses 800x600.

I tried to set a lower desktop resolution but it didn't affect what happens when I launch these games.

This happens in different games: "Starbound", "Star Wars: Knights of the Old Republic", "Baldurs Gate II".

The tablet has an Intel HD video.

How to fix it?

Comment: Some games will let you hit (left)Alt+Enter once or twice to resolve such issue. Might work for some, or all or none, give it a shot.

Comment: @ИвоНедев no, it doesn't help. I can play some of them in maximized windowed mode but when I press alt+enter or set full screen in options it behaves like I wrote in the question.

Comment: Perhaps [**this answer**](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/191836/46740) has the solution to your problem?

Comment: @Nolonar thanks, "Disable display scaling on high DPI settings" works! If you write an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are experiencing a problem related to DPI scaling, as is usual with most mobile PCs running at resolutions close to or above Full HD (1920 x 1080) due to their relatively small size.

To fix this, you can disable DPI scaling. [**This answer**](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/191836/46740) explains how.

---

Keep in mind that disabling display scaling can lead to issues, where UI elements are rendered too small to be read. This is arguably a better outcome than not being able to see most of the game, however.